# Difference between current_allocation s total_allocation in MySQL sys.memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, amazon-rds, memory

I'm trying to debug a memory leak in MySQL 5.7.37 and running the following query gives me insights about the threads running and the memory allocation for each thread.

```
select * from sys.memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes
```

The output shows some of the threads having the total_allocated value in GiB. However, the current_allocated value is still in MiB. Some of the values I see are as follows:

> - current_count_used => 1783
> - current_allocated  => 262.46MiB
> - current_avg_alloc  => 150.74KiB
> - current_max_alloc  => 259.49MiB
> - total_alloc        => 16.07GiB

How could I interpret the above data? Does that mean the total_allocated memory is reserved from the RAM for this thread?

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-memory-by-thread-by-current-bytes.html):
current_allocated - The current number of allocated bytes that have not been freed yet for the thread

total_allocated - The **total memory allocation** in bytes for the thread.

Additional queries may give you some more information

```
select * from sys.memory_global_total;
select thd_id,conn_id, current_memory from sys.session;
select * from memory_summary_by_thread_by_event_name where thread_id= "ID of the thread with high memory usage" order by CURRENT_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED;
select thread_id, user, current_allocated from memory_by_thread_by_current_bytes;
```

Common causes for high memory usage can be:

- Multiple Statements in One Query
- Buffer pool issues (can be because of "cold" database (fresh start), a lot of dirty pages)
- Temporary table issues
- other issues

For more details you can check [this page](https://support.huaweicloud.com/intl/en-us/bestpractice-rds/rds_02_0017.html).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).